# Putting an Identifier based on condition in column data in powerquery

Tags: excel, powerquery

I would like to know how I can put a unique identifier for a value in power query. I am not sure if I am explaining in a right way but the story is like this.
In normal excel process, I would sort a column by its values so if there multiple cells with same value then it would put an identifier in first instance. For example we have data as follows:

> ```
> +---------------+
> |       A       |
> +---------------+
> | Column Header |
> | 5             |
> | 5             |
> | 6             |
> | 7             |
> | 7             |
> +---------------+
> ```

I use first sort and then use following formula in column B:

```
=if(A2=A1;"";"Unique")
```

which would result in

> ```
> +---------------+--------+
> |       A       |   B    |
> +---------------+--------+
> | Column Header |        |
> | 5             | Unique |
> | 5             |        |
> | 6             | Unique |
> | 7             | Unique |
> | 7             |        |
> +---------------+--------+
> ```

Here I can have "Unique" or any string for my identifier, but I just want to know how can I do the same in power query. I would appreciate the help.
BR

`Div/Mat` column has the value that I want to put unique identifier in first instance:

[image: Div/Mat col has the value that i want to put unique identifier in first instance]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have already sorted your table accordingly, start by adding an index column:

```
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(PriorStep, "Index", 0, 1),
```

Then you can add a custom column which compares each row with the previous row, based on the Index value:

```
#"Added Unique" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Unique", each if [Index] = 0 then "Unique" else if #"Added Index"{[Index]}[Header] <> #"Added Index"{[Index] - 1}[Header] then "Unique" else null),
```

Finally, remove the Index column:

```
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Unique",{"Index"})
```

Alternatively: you may wish to find the first occurrence of a value in an unsorted table - this approach will do that (and will of course still work for a sorted table):

```
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(PriorStep, "Index", 0, 1),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Index", {"Header"}, {{"MinIndex", each List.Min([Index]), type number}}),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Index",{"Header", "Index"},#"Grouped Rows",{"Header", "MinIndex"},"Group",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Added First Occurrence" = Table.AddColumn(#"Merged Queries", "First Occurrence", each if Table.IsEmpty([Group]) then null else "First"),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added First Occurrence",{"Index", "Group"})
```

Comment: Hi Olly, I am going through your recommendation as it looks more to be usefull for me. But I am wondering what is happening. I am getting Invalid identifier error and it is in [Header]. I have replaced the Header with actual header name but yet it is not working.
For your information, I am comparing the text values between different rows, not as number in my initial question. Would be glad to know what I am doing wrong. Br,

Comment: [Edit] your question to show a sample of your actual table structure / data, and the code you are trying.

Comment: Hi Olly,
Here is the code :-
My code :-  #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Filtered Rows",{{"Div/Mat", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "Index", 0, 1),
    #"Added Unique" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Unique Mat/Div", each if [Index] = 0 then "Unique" else if #"Added Index"{[Index]}[Div/Mat] <> #"Added Index"{[Index] - 1}[Div/Mat] then "Unique" else null)
in
    #"Added Unique"

I get error :- Invalid identifier and it locates to [Div/Mat]

Comment: You have a special character in your field name, so you need to wrap it in `#""` - so the line becomes: `#"Added Unique" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Unique Mat/Div", each if [Index] = 0 then "Unique" else if #"Added Index"{[Index]}[#"Div/Mat"] <> #"Added Index"{[Index] - 1}[#"Div/Mat"] then "Unique" else null)`

Comment: Thanks a lot lot lot. That worked. Wish you a good day ahead.

Comment: Hi, Sorry that i am asking too much of questions, but I am new to query so not getting quite well with it. I have like 4k rows of data with nearly 50 Columns. I notice that after index method, query loads super slow. Is there someways to speed up ?`BR, Manoj

Comment: Using my second suggested approach should be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way:

I bring in the table as you described it, sort it, group it, then change the first item of each group to "Unique" using List.ReplaceRange. Then I expand the list to new rows. It gives me this:

[image]

I then remove the AllData column:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", Int64.Type}}),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Changed Type",{{"Column1", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Sorted Rows", {"Column1"}, {{"AllData", each _, type table}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each List.ReplaceRange([AllData][Column1],0,1,{"Unique"})),
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom"),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Custom",{"AllData"})
in
#"Removed Columns"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, perhaps easier, and you don't have to sort the values.

See the code and comments below.

```
let
Source = Table.FromColumns({{5,5,6,7,6}},{"Values"}),
```

// An example table, use your Excel table instead.

```
WithIndex = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index"),
```

// Add an "Index" column to the "Source" table.

```
NewUniqueColumn = Table.AddColumn(WithIndex, "Is_Unique", each List.PositionOf(WithIndex[Values],[Values]) = [Index])
```

// Add a new column to the "WithIndex" table named "Is_Unique" with True or False values.

// The third argument is a formula applied to each row:

// WithIndex[Values] returns a list from the Values column.

// [Value] is the value of this row.

// List.PositionOf(WithIndex[Values],[Values]) returns the position of the first occurence of the value (from the row) in the list of values.

// Then it checks the result against [index] (the value of the index column of this row) and returns a boolean (true or false)

```
in

NewUniqueColumn
```

You can copy + paste this code to see how it works:

```
let
Source = Table.FromColumns({{5,5,6,7,6}},{"Values"}),
WithIndex = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index"),
NewUniqueColumn = Table.AddColumn(WithIndex, "Is_Unique", each List.PositionOf(WithIndex[Values],[Values]) = [Index])
in
NewUniqueColumn
```

Now you can delete the index column and change the "True/False" values if needed.

Hope it helps.